# Vim LatexSuite: how to define IMAP that also moves the cursor?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I am using latexsuite in vim and I'm trying to make `MBF` in insert mode expand to `\mathbf{}<++>` and *place the cursor inside the brackets*.

The following:

```
:call IMAP('MBF', "\\mathbf{}<++>\<Left>\<Left>\<Left>\<Left>\<Left>",'tex')
```

produces this:

```
`\mathbf{}<80>kl<80>kl<80>kl<80>kl<80>kl`.
```

Whereas the following

```
    :call IMAP('MBF', "\\mathbf{}<++><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>",'tex')
```

produces this:

```
\mathbf{}<Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I write an IMAP function that puts the cursor inside the brackets after expanding `MBF` to `\mathbf{}<++>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert a placeholder `<++>` where you want the cursor to be placed. In your particular example, you should use:

```
:call IMAP('MBF', "\\mathbf{<++>}<++>",'tex')
```

This produces

```
\mathbf{}<++>
```

with the cursor inside the braces.